# Neo4j: run program several times on same data without creating duplicates

Tags: java, c#, database, neo4j, cypher

I have a list of POCO shoes and create them in the database with:

```
foreach (Shoe shoe in shoes)
{
    client.Cypher.Create("(shoe:Shoe {shoe})")
        .WithParam("shoe", shoe).ExecuteWithoutResults();
}
```

If I add new shoes to my list and run the program again, the shoes already save and are then created again. How can I avoid this? (
The shoes' id is a GUID created on runtime, if that matters).

I think I could be able to solve this using MERGE but not sure how to use this with POCOs?

Comment: select shoe from shoes; if null -> persist new shoe

Comment: @Stultuske I tried this : MATCH ($shoe) RETURN CASE WHEN shoe=null THEN Create (shoe:Shoe {shoe}) but I get an error

Comment: what language is that?

Comment: It's Cypher query language

Comment: so, why don't you tag this as Cypher, instead of java and c#